# How to use Conditional Formating in matrix in Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I am using Excel 2010 where I created a Pivot table. In the table, I want to highlight those values whose difference with the preceding value should be greater than 5%. Here is the table-

Column1
7.14%
28.57%
64.29%
0.00%
0.00%
1.00%

Column2
0.26%
0.43%
2.46%
1.73%
7.34%
6.48%

Column3
0.10%
0.21%
0.88%
1.62%
2.74%
0.22%

Now here, the formula must go row by row. See if 7.14%-0.26%>5.0%, then highlight 7.14 and 0.26. 
Similarly, in last row, it must highlight all 3 cell values, 1.00%, 6.48% and 0.22% since the difference between 1%-6.48% and 0.22%-6.48% is greater than 5%.

Please keep in mind that the difference must be in absolute values.Should not be affected by which value is subtracted with which.
Can someone please help??

Answer (score 0):

I can accomplish the required highlighting using four conditional formatting equations if that is of any use.

```
`=ABS(A1-B1)>5%` applies to `$A$1:$A$6`
`=ABS(A1-B1)>5%` applies to `$B$1:$B$6`
`=ABS(B1-C1)>5%` applies to `$B$1:$B$6`
`=ABS(B1-C1)>5%` applies to `$C$1:$C$6`
```

[image: Table with required conditional formatting]

Comment: Ya. But, this doesn't solve the problem. I have this table in the form of a pivot table. And as soon as I change the slicers to new settings, the values in columns change. And, sometime there might not even be column C. So, I want a dynamic equation that enables me to run through the entire pivot table and select values that are at 5% difference from each other.